# Incorrectly phrasing a nested select statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, nested, derived

I want to select into table Koppels from a table "Deelnames" with columns "Speler", "hcp", "Wedstrijd", "speelt", "vroeg", "laat":

- each D1Speler who plays in a certain match:

  - "speelt" =-1,
  - value for "Wedstrijd"
- With each of them: the 10 D2Spelers which fit him best:

  - "speelt", "Wedstrijd" same as D1,
  - "vroeg", "laat" not violating,
  - smallest differences between D1hcp and D2hcp of all candidate couples.

Whatever way I write it, I get the reply "Every derived table must have its own alias"

Please tell me how to spell this out correctly for MySQL.

```
INSERT INTO Koppels (
    D1Speler, D1Hcp, D1vroeg, D1laat, 
    D2Speler, D2Hcp, D2vroeg, D2laat)
SELECT 
   D1.Speler AS D1Speler, D1.hcp As D1Hcp, D1.vroeg AS D1vroeg, D1.laat AS D1laat,
   D2Speler, D2Hcp, D2vroeg, D2laat
FROM 
   Deelnames AS D1,
     (Select Speler AS D2Speler, hcp AS D2Hcp, vroeg AS D2vroeg, laat AS D2laat, Wedstrijd, speelt 
        FROM Deelnames
        WHERE D1.Speler <> Speler
        AND speelt=-1
        AND Wedstrijd = "M01"
        AND NOT ((D1.vroeg =-1 AND laat =-1) OR (D1.laat=-1 AND vroeg = -1))
        ORDER BY ABS(D1.hcp-hcp) ASC
        LIMIT 10)
WHERE 
       D1.speelt=-1
   AND D1.Wedstrijd="M01"
```

Thanks for helping me out.

Fred Ottenhof

Comment: please report the error you get when executing INSERT command

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Please try the updated version of the query:

```
INSERT INTO Koppels (
    D1Speler, D1Hcp, D1vroeg, D1laat, 
    D2Speler, D2Hcp, D2vroeg, D2laat)
SELECT 
   D1.Speler AS D1Speler, D1.hcp As D1Hcp, D1.vroeg AS D1vroeg, D1.laat AS D1laat,
   D2.D2Speler, D2.D2Hcp, D2.D2vroeg, D2.D2laat
FROM
    Deelnames AS D1
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
           _tmp_D1.Speler AS _tmp_D1_Speler,
           _tmp_D1.hcp AS _tmp_D1_hcp,
           _tmp_D2._tmp_D2_Wedstrijd,
           _tmp_D2._tmp_D2_speelt,
           _tmp_D2.D2Speler, _tmp_D2.D2Hcp, _tmp_D2.D2vroeg, _tmp_D2.D2laat
        FROM 
           Deelnames AS _tmp_D1
           INNER JOIN 
           (    
                Select 
                    Speler AS D2Speler, 
                    hcp AS D2Hcp, 
                    vroeg AS D2vroeg, 
                    laat AS D2laat, 
                    Wedstrijd AS _tmp_D2_Wedstrijd, 
                    speelt AS _tmp_D2_speelt
                FROM 
                    Deelnames
                WHERE 
                    speelt=-1
                    AND Wedstrijd = "M01"
            ) AS _tmp_D2 
                ON _tmp_D1.Speler <> _tmp_D2.D2Speler
                   AND NOT ((_tmp_D1.vroeg =-1 AND _tmp_D2.D2laat =-1) OR (_tmp_D1.laat=-1 AND _tmp_D2.D2vroeg = -1))
                   AND _tmp_D1.speelt = _tmp_D2._tmp_D2_speelt
                   AND _tmp_D1.Wedstrijd = _tmp_D2._tmp_D2_Wedstrijd
        ORDER BY 
            ABS(_tmp_D1.hcp-_tmp_D2.D2hcp) ASC
        LIMIT 10
    ) AS D2
        ON D1.Speler = D2._tmp_D1_Speler
           AND D1.speelt = D2._tmp_D2_speelt
           AND D1.Wedstrijd = D2._tmp_D2_Wedstrijd  
           AND D1.hcp = D2._tmp_D1_hcp
```

Comment: Thanks for this improvement. After a minute change ("D2Speler" instead of "D2.Speler") the query ran. It resulted in 10 entries, conforming to "Limit 10".

Comment: The only remaining problem is that the Limit now applies to D1 instead of to D2. I have some 80 different D1.Spelers, and with each I want the 10 D2.Spelers fitting best. Should result in some 800 entries. How can I achieve that effect ?

Comment: I tried to build upon your suggestion: pulled the ORDER BY and LIMIT 10 into the D2 Select. See the rephrased query above. Now I get the error message "unknown column D1.vroeg (or D1.vroeg) in WHERE claus". Seems we're almost there. How to refer to the outside world from within the D2 Select ?

Comment: @FredOttenhof  Hi Fred. Please find my updated answer with the new query version. I'm not 100% sure if this query would completely solve your problem, but I hope it would help a little, Regards.

Comment: T-G, Thanks for the next attempt.

Comment: I tried it out immediately. Unfortunately it resulted in thesame 10 entries onlywhich the former attempt resulted in. I'll take an good look coming weekend at what you created to see if I can explain that. Fred.